# Segue transition like the iPhone Messages/Settings applications

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'd like to switch view controllers using a custom segue where the new controller comes from the right and over the old one - just like in the iPhone standard Settings/Messages apps

I tried the following custom segue:

```
-(void)perform {

   UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
   UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];                   

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



    [destinationController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];       
}
```

but the animation is not as i want. old screen disappears and the new controller comes from right over a black background.

I have tried all the `kaTransition` types.

I there something I missed, or is there any other way to perform that animation?

Answer (score 0):

The settings and messages applications are built using a navigation controller. The animation you are describing above is the default push (show in iOS 8) animation. In order to achieve this you just need your root view controller to be within a navigation controller. Then call

```
self.navigationController pushViewControll:vC animated:Yes];
```

This was create the animation below. If this is not what you want to achieve please show me your current animation and i will try my best to help you